# Strange Error when using AVAudioRecorder with MPEG4AAC

Tags: objective-c, ios, avaudioplayer, avaudiorecorder

I have tested this on two different iPad3s and on one I can record and playback both .m4a and .caf files on the other I can only playback .caf files.

What I do is record a .m4a-file using the setting

```
AVFormatIDKey set to kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC
```

On the one iPad it works fine. If I test it on the other iPad I get the error "OSStatus error 1685348671" when I try to play the file recorded.

However if I comment out that setting and record as a .caf-file it works flawlessly.

Here the relevant code snippets:

```
NSDictionary *recorderSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                      //[NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC], AVFormatIDKey,
                                      [NSNumber numberWithInt:AVAudioQualityMin], AVEncoderAudioQualityKey,
                                      [NSNumber numberWithInt:16], AVEncoderBitRateKey,
                                      [NSNumber numberWithInt:1], AVNumberOfChannelsKey,
                                      [NSNumber numberWithFloat:16000.0], AVSampleRateKey, nil];
```

I then go and call a simple

```
AudioRecorder *audioRecorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:soundFileURL settings:recorderSettings error:&error];
```

To play back I call

```
AudioPlayer *audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundFileURL error:&error];
[audioPlayer play];
```

Thanks